# Cannot ping linux server from windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, networking, switch

I have 3 devices all connected via a switch.

> 1) Windows 7 PC
>
> 2) Windows 2012 server
>
> 3) RHEL 6.8 Linux server

Devices 1 & 2 need to be able to access a web application on the Linux server.

2 can ping 3 fine and vice versa. The web application also works fine from 2.

1 cannot ping 3 although I sometimes get something like:

Reply from w.x.y.z destination host unreachable

Now I understand having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110622/ping-response-request-timed-out-vs-destination-host-unreachable), that this indicates a problem with the routing at w.x.y.z.

Device 1 has a 10.x.x.x IP address
Device 3 has a 192.x.x.x IP address
Device 2 has a 10.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x addresses set up

I'm not too familiar with networking so I'm not sure what to try next. It feels like a need a bridge between the networks somehow?

**EDIT:**

OK, so I moved 1 to the 192 range but it still wouldn't work. However, once I change the 3rd octet of 1 to match 3 it started playing. I'm pleased this worked but don't really understand why. Anyone?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to give Device 1 a 192.x.x.x IP address instead of the one it has?

Comment: +1 @n8te - Separating the networks will make it harder for yourself. You would need something to route the traffic if you want to still keep it separated. Getting server 2 to route the traffic from 1 to 3 would be doable, since it has one interface in each network.

Comment: You do **not have to** give all pcs IP addresses from the same subnet, if you have a good reason not to. You can leave everything as it is, but to make it work you will have to set a few things right. So: when pinging Linux from 1, are you using the IP address or the name? Are you using static IP addresses or DHCP? If DHCP, who is giving them out?

Comment: 1) Devices 3 has ` 192.x.x.x IP` as in a public 192.something.x.x  or as in 192.168.x.x?  2) Without network masks or CIRD information there is not enough information to answer. E.g you could have the network 192.168.x.x/16 (everything starting with 192.168) or 192.168.3.x/24 (which would be everything starting with 192.168.3 (but not 192.168.1.x).

Comment: @Hennes I'm gradually getting my head round the subnet mask thing. As I understand it, for all 3 of these machines to talk, their IP addresses all need to fall within the minimum range defined by all subnet masks. So if one machine had a mask of 255.255.255.0 and another had 255.255.0.0, I'd only have about 255 addresses to play with. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes and no. The broadcast address (needed for ARP) also changes. Maybe this post can help: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score -1):

It appears that device1, the Windows 7 PC, lives on a different network than device3, the linux box. Device2, the Windows server, has connections to both networks. If you are on a corporate network, you need to contact your network team, because they may have good reasons for your Win7 PC to not be able to communicate with that network. You basically have a routing problem that lives outside these three machines, unless the Windows server acts as a network bridge (not likely).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: For info - these are 3 machines in a private network connected with a switch in a lab. They're not on a corporate network.